# JavaScript Fiscal Year issue

Tags: javascript

I need help with my script.
It's supposed to check that month and year is within the current fiscal year (Oct. 2013 - Sep. 2014)

My test date is (Apr 2015) but it's coming up within the current fiscal year which is false.

```
if ( prevYear == ListYr || ( 
   ( month == "Oct" || month == "Nov" || month == "Dec" )) || 
   ( curYear == ListYr || (month == "Jan" || month == "Feb" || month == "Mar" ||         
   month=="Apr" || month == "May" || month == "Jun" || month == "Jul" 
   || month == "Aug" ||  month=="Sep")))
{
       alert("Within Fiscal Year");
} else {
       alert('outwith fiscal year');   
}
```

Any ideas or a better way to make it more efficient?

Thanks!

Comment: you're going to be downvoted heavily if you don't post your code here and and if you cheat the SO filter like this

Comment: That's how you achieve this: http://jsfiddle.net/4DFUL/15/

Comment: @AmitJoki , I'm confused.  What do you mean downvoted? and how did I cheat the SO?  Explain so I don't do it again.

Comment: @Isaac, downvoted in the sense -5 as of now. You aren't allowed to include a link to jsfiddle unless you also copy the code in it here. You've cheated this filter by formatting the link as code

Comment: @AmitJoki, can you please take away the negative points since I  have removed the jsfiddle.  Now I know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IT's a bit clunky but I think this does what you want..

```
if ( prevYear == ListYr && ( 
 ( month == "Oct" || month == "Nov" || month == "Dec" ) ) || 
 ( curYear == ListYr && (month == "Jan" || month == "Feb" || month == "Mar" || month=="Apr" || month == "May" || month == "Jun" || month == "Jul" || month == "Aug" || month=="Sep"))) {
 alert("Within Fiscal Year");
} else {
 alert('outwith fiscal year');   
}
```